# draw vertical borders but keep count of previous input

Tags: excel, vba

I am quite new to VBA I am still trying to get an idea how to get it going.
I don't know how to make the vertical borders repeat themselves on each button press, but not in the same place.

Example:

I press button 5 -> Text input like a table -> Draw vertical lines until the text stops.

I press button 15 now -> Text input like a table -> Draw vertical lines until text stops.

I will uppload the file for you to see better and the Code...

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DoFive()
Dim LRow As Long                ' Row in which to place data

' Initalize Data
LRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row        ' Current last row with data

If LRow = 0 Then                                    ' It's the first set
    LRow = 4
Else
    LRow = LRow + 3                                 ' It's a follow-on set
End If

' Put in the borders
DoBorders Range("A" & LRow & ":AM" & LRow + 5)       ' Calculate the new range
Cells(LRow, "B").Interior.ColorIndex = 16
Cells(LRow, "E").Interior.ColorIndex = 50
Cells(LRow, "F").Interior.ColorIndex = 43
Cells(LRow, "A").Interior.ColorIndex = 22
Cells(LRow, "D").Interior.ColorIndex = 22
Cells(LRow, "C").Interior.ColorIndex = 45
Cells(LRow, "N").Interior.ColorIndex = 50
Cells(LRow, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = 45
Cells(LRow, "I").Interior.ColorIndex = "19"
Cells(LRow, "J").Interior.ColorIndex = "19"
Cells(LRow, "K").Interior.ColorIndex = "19"
Cells(LRow, "L").Interior.ColorIndex = "19"
Cells(LRow, "M").Interior.ColorIndex = "19"
Cells(LRow + 1, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = "3"
Cells(LRow + 2, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = "3"
Cells(LRow + 3, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = "3"
Cells(LRow + 4, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = "3"
Cells(LRow + 5, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = "3"

' Fill the new range with data
Cells(LRow, "A").Value = "Bought At"
Cells(LRow, "B").Value = "#"
Cells(LRow, "C").Value = "Name of Stock"
Cells(LRow, "D").Value = "Sell After"
Cells(LRow, "E").Value = "Sold Date"
Cells(LRow, "F").Value = "Profit"
Cells(LRow, "H").Value = "Name"
Cells(LRow, "I").Value = "1"
Cells(LRow, "J").Value = "2"
Cells(LRow, "K").Value = "3"
Cells(LRow, "L").Value = "4"
Cells(LRow, "M").Value = "5"
Cells(LRow, "N").Value = "Data"

Cells(LRow + 1, "B").Value = "1"
Cells(LRow + 2, "B").Value = "2"
Cells(LRow + 3, "B").Value = "3"
Cells(LRow + 4, "B").Value = "4"
Cells(LRow + 5, "B").Value = "5"

Cells(LRow + 1, "H").Value = "Price"
Cells(LRow + 2, "H").Value = "Price"
Cells(LRow + 3, "H").Value = "Price"
Cells(LRow + 4, "H").Value = "Price"
Cells(LRow + 5, "H").Value = "Price"

End Sub

Sub DoEight()
Dim LRow As Long                ' Row in which to place data

' Initalize Data
LRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row        ' Current last row with data

If LRow = 0 Then                                    ' It's the first set
    LRow = 4
Else
    LRow = LRow + 3                                 ' It's a follow-on set
End If

' Put in the borders
DoBorders Range("A" & LRow & ":AM" & LRow + 8)       ' Calculate the new range
Cells(LRow, "B").Interior.ColorIndex = 16
Cells(LRow, "E").Interior.ColorIndex = 50
Cells(LRow, "F").Interior.ColorIndex = 43
Cells(LRow, "A").Interior.ColorIndex = 22
Cells(LRow, "D").Interior.ColorIndex = 22
Cells(LRow, "C").Interior.ColorIndex = 45
Cells(LRow, "Q").Interior.ColorIndex = 50
Cells(LRow, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = 45
Cells(LRow, "I").Interior.ColorIndex = "19"
Cells(LRow, "J").Interior.ColorIndex = "19"
Cells(LRow, "K").Interior.ColorIndex = "19"
Cells(LRow, "L").Interior.ColorIndex = "19"
Cells(LRow, "M").Interior.ColorIndex = "19"
Cells(LRow, "N").Interior.ColorIndex = "19"
Cells(LRow, "O").Interior.ColorIndex = "19"
Cells(LRow, "P").Interior.ColorIndex = "19"
Cells(LRow + 1, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = "3"
Cells(LRow + 2, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = "3"
Cells(LRow + 3, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = "3"
Cells(LRow + 4, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = "3"
Cells(LRow + 5, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = "3"
Cells(LRow + 6, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = "3"
Cells(LRow + 7, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = "3"
Cells(LRow + 8, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = "3"
' Fill the new range with data
Cells(LRow, "A").Value = "Bought At"
Cells(LRow, "B").Value = "#"
Cells(LRow, "C").Value = "Name of Stock"
Cells(LRow, "D").Value = "Sell After"
Cells(LRow, "E").Value = "Sold Date"
Cells(LRow, "F").Value = "Profit"
Cells(LRow, "H").Value = "Name"
Cells(LRow, "I").Value = "1"
Cells(LRow, "J").Value = "2"
Cells(LRow, "K").Value = "3"
Cells(LRow, "L").Value = "4"
Cells(LRow, "M").Value = "5"
Cells(LRow, "N").Value = "6"
Cells(LRow, "O").Value = "7"
Cells(LRow, "P").Value = "8"
Cells(LRow, "Q").Value = "Data"

Cells(LRow + 1, "B").Value = "1"
Cells(LRow + 2, "B").Value = "2"
Cells(LRow + 3, "B").Value = "3"
Cells(LRow + 4, "B").Value = "4"
Cells(LRow + 5, "B").Value = "5"
Cells(LRow + 6, "B").Value = "6"
Cells(LRow + 7, "B").Value = "7"
Cells(LRow + 8, "B").Value = "8"

Cells(LRow + 1, "H").Value = "Price"
Cells(LRow + 2, "H").Value = "Price"
Cells(LRow + 3, "H").Value = "Price"
Cells(LRow + 4, "H").Value = "Price"
Cells(LRow + 5, "H").Value = "Price"
Cells(LRow + 6, "H").Value = "Price"
Cells(LRow + 7, "H").Value = "Price"
Cells(LRow + 8, "H").Value = "Price"
End Sub
Sub DoFifteen()
Dim LRow As Long                ' Row in which to place data

' Initalize Data
LRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row        ' Current last row with data

If LRow = 0 Then                                    ' It's the first set
    LRow = 4
Else
    LRow = LRow + 3                                 ' It's a follow-on set
End If

' Put in the borders
DoBorders Range("A" & LRow & ":AM" & LRow + 15)       ' Calculate the new range
Cells(LRow, "B").Interior.ColorIndex = 16
Cells(LRow, "E").Interior.ColorIndex = 50
Cells(LRow, "F").Interior.ColorIndex = 43
Cells(LRow, "A").Interior.ColorIndex = 22
Cells(LRow, "D").Interior.ColorIndex = 22
Cells(LRow, "C").Interior.ColorIndex = 45
Cells(LRow, "X").Interior.ColorIndex = 50
Cells(LRow, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = 45
Cells(LRow, "I").Interior.ColorIndex = "19"
Cells(LRow, "J").Interior.ColorIndex = "19"
Cells(LRow, "K").Interior.ColorIndex = "19"
Cells(LRow, "L").Interior.ColorIndex = "19"
Cells(LRow, "M").Interior.ColorIndex = "19"
Cells(LRow, "N").Interior.ColorIndex = "19"
Cells(LRow, "O").Interior.ColorIndex = "19"
Cells(LRow, "P").Interior.ColorIndex = "19"
Cells(LRow, "Q").Interior.ColorIndex = "19"
Cells(LRow, "R").Interior.ColorIndex = "19"
Cells(LRow, "S").Interior.ColorIndex = "19"
Cells(LRow, "T").Interior.ColorIndex = "19"
Cells(LRow, "U").Interior.ColorIndex = "19"
Cells(LRow, "V").Interior.ColorIndex = "19"
Cells(LRow, "W").Interior.ColorIndex = "19"
Cells(LRow + 1, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = "3"
Cells(LRow + 2, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = "3"
Cells(LRow + 3, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = "3"
Cells(LRow + 4, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = "3"
Cells(LRow + 5, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = "3"
Cells(LRow + 6, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = "3"
Cells(LRow + 7, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = "3"
Cells(LRow + 8, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = "3"
Cells(LRow + 9, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = "3"
Cells(LRow + 10, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = "3"
Cells(LRow + 11, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = "3"
Cells(LRow + 12, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = "3"
Cells(LRow + 13, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = "3"
Cells(LRow + 14, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = "3"
Cells(LRow + 15, "H").Interior.ColorIndex = "3"
' Fill the new range with data
Cells(LRow, "A").Value = "Bought At"
Cells(LRow, "B").Value = "#"
Cells(LRow, "C").Value = "Name of Stock"
Cells(LRow, "D").Value = "Sell After"
Cells(LRow, "E").Value = "Sold Date"
Cells(LRow, "F").Value = "Profit"
Cells(LRow, "H").Value = "Name"
Cells(LRow, "I").Value = "1"
Cells(LRow, "J").Value = "2"
Cells(LRow, "K").Value = "3"
Cells(LRow, "L").Value = "4"
Cells(LRow, "M").Value = "5"
Cells(LRow, "N").Value = "6"
Cells(LRow, "O").Value = "7"
Cells(LRow, "P").Value = "8"
Cells(LRow, "Q").Value = "9"
Cells(LRow, "R").Value = "10"
Cells(LRow, "S").Value = "11"
Cells(LRow, "T").Value = "12"
Cells(LRow, "U").Value = "13"
Cells(LRow, "V").Value = "14"
Cells(LRow, "W").Value = "15"
Cells(LRow, "X").Value = "Data"

Cells(LRow + 1, "B").Value = "1"
Cells(LRow + 2, "B").Value = "2"
Cells(LRow + 3, "B").Value = "3"
Cells(LRow + 4, "B").Value = "4"
Cells(LRow + 5, "B").Value = "5"
Cells(LRow + 6, "B").Value = "6"
Cells(LRow + 7, "B").Value = "7"
Cells(LRow + 8, "B").Value = "8"
Cells(LRow + 9, "B").Value = "9"
Cells(LRow + 10, "B").Value = "10"
Cells(LRow + 11, "B").Value = "11"
Cells(LRow + 12, "B").Value = "12"
Cells(LRow + 13, "B").Value = "13"
Cells(LRow + 14, "B").Value = "14"
Cells(LRow + 15, "B").Value = "15"

Cells(LRow + 1, "H").Value = "Price"
Cells(LRow + 2, "H").Value = "Price"
Cells(LRow + 3, "H").Value = "Price"
Cells(LRow + 4, "H").Value = "Price"
Cells(LRow + 5, "H").Value = "Price"
Cells(LRow + 6, "H").Value = "Price"
Cells(LRow + 7, "H").Value = "Price"
Cells(LRow + 8, "H").Value = "Price"
Cells(LRow + 9, "H").Value = "Price"
Cells(LRow + 10, "H").Value = "Price"
Cells(LRow + 11, "H").Value = "Price"
Cells(LRow + 12, "H").Value = "Price"
Cells(LRow + 13, "H").Value = "Price"
Cells(LRow + 14, "H").Value = "Price"
Cells(LRow + 15, "H").Value = "Price"

End Sub
Sub DoBorders(rng As Range)

With rng
    .Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
    With .Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThick
        End With

    With .Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThick
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

and dl of the file: https://mega.nz/#!BssHyJQa!HCwyJ5h0BbVeOJc4CkwohcoFAXJQ9bbfJ6q1PcQZuJs

What I'm trying to achieve:
http://ibb.co/dHfYha

See the vertical borders between "Name of Stock", "Sold Date", "Profit", those I don't know how to make them and repeat everytime I press a button 5 8 or 15...

Comment: Why not use a hidden sheet where you already have 5,8,15 row tables created beforehand? At the click of the button simply copy across the table to the relevant row? You don't have to recreate the rows, colouring etc again and again. It is less messy

Comment: I know..its just this is how I feel it fulfills my needs...I think with coloring and everything makes it look better... even tho it's a wall of text

Comment: I don't think you got my point :). You can create and color the tables once manually in the hidden sheet. In the button click, simply copy tables to the new row. This way you do not have to create and color it again :)

Comment: Ah I see, but I would still be able to keep the 2 rows space between input creations? I don't know how to do it can you please give few extra tips?Thank you.

Comment: there are many ways you can do that. The most simplest way is to ask the user to select the row where you want the table and then click on the button ;)

Comment: Well yes, but in this case, it wouldn't keep count of previous input. I want always to keep 2 rows in between inputs of the button pressed...despite which button I choose to press. Maybe is 5 then 8 , then 5 again, then 8 again.And so on.

Comment: Then after every paste, keep a record of the next row in hidden sheet :)